# Passing a string to set the default language does not work

Tags: javascript, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, ngx-translate

I am currently working on an app that does translation work. The English language should be used as the default setting. The actual translation is done by `ngx-translate`. It is temporarily stored in the variable `translateService`, which is declared in the constructor.

the constructor:

```
constructor(private translateService: TranslateService, private platform: Platform, private globalization: Globalization, private storage: Storage)
```

The variable `defaultLang` is provided with the string `'en'`, which stands for English. The `translateService` now receives the variable `defaultLang`. But still, English is not taken as the default language. What is the reason for this?

```
async initialize() {
if (this.isInitialized) { return Promise.resolve(); } if (this.initializeListeners.length > 0) { // a parallel call has already been started 
    return new Promise(success => { this.initializeListeners.push(success); });
} return new Promise(async success => {
    let defaultLang = 'en'; this.translateService.setDefaultLang(defaultLang); this.initializeListeners.push(success); await this.platform.ready(); let lang = await this.storage.get(LanguageService.STORAGE_KEY); if (!lang && checkAvailability(Globalization.getPluginRef(), null, Globalization.getPluginName()) === true) { 
// no previous language found -> get device language 
        try {
            let preferredLanguage = await this.globalization.getPreferredLanguage(); if (preferredLanguage && preferredLanguage.value) {
                lang = preferredLanguage.value; if (lang.indexOf('-') > -1) { lang = lang.split('-')[0]; } if (lang.indexOf('_') > -1) { lang = lang.split('_')[0]; } lang = lang.toLowerCase(); if (this.availableLanguages.indexOf(lang) == -1) {
                    // detected language is not available 
                    lang = null;
                }
            }
        } catch (e) { }
    } if (!lang) { lang = defaultLang; } this.textDirection = this.rtlLanguages.indexOf(lang) >= 0 ? 'rtl' : 'ltr';
    this.platform.setDir(this.rtlLanguages.indexOf(lang) >= 0 ? 'rtl' : 'ltr', true); await this.translateService.use(lang); setTimeout(() => {
        // use timeout to let language switch propagate 
        this.isInitialized = true; this.initializeListeners.map(success => { success(); }); this.initializeListeners = null;
    }, 100);
});
}
```

I assumed that the declaration of a variable passing the corresponding string would be sufficient.